# Proving D matrix of the Lorenz group furnish a representation using a transformation rule

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory

Given a transformation rule:

$$U^\dagger(\Lambda)\hat\Psi(x)U(\Lambda)=\sum_{\hat\sigma=1}^4D_{\sigma\tilde\sigma}(\Lambda)\hat\Psi_{\tilde\sigma}(\Lambda^{-1} x)$$

when $\Lambda$ is the homogenous Lorenz transformation acting on spacetime coordinate $x=x^{\mu}$,

$U(\Lambda) $ is the corresponding Unitary operator that acting on Hilbert space as expected by Wigner theorem,$ \hat\Psi(x)$ is a field operator (corresponding to some general particle). and  $D_{\sigma \tilde\sigma}(\Lambda)$ is a matrix element of the D matrix corresponding to the "field space" and not necessarily have to be unitary.

from the transformation law above, I need to prove that the D matrix furnish a Representation i.e.:
for all $\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2$ that satisfy $\eta_{\mu\nu}\Lambda^{\mu}_\alpha\Lambda^{\nu}_\beta=\eta_{\alpha\beta}$
I need to show that:
$$D(\Lambda_1)D(\Lambda_2)=D(\Lambda_1\Lambda_2)$$

I tried to substitute $\Lambda=\Lambda_1\Lambda_2$ in the transformation rule but I didn't succeed in receiving the required separation.

Comment: Your equation has no matching $\sigma$ on the left side.

Comment: Do you understand what $U(\Lambda_1\Lambda_2)$ is?

Comment: I know generally how its look a like; but I have to ask my lecturer if he mean we can use it

Comment: I don’t see how you can make progress unless you do something with it.